# Eliminating variables from an SOCP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Given an SOCP problem

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}&w^Tx\\
\text{subject to} &\|A_i x + b_i\|_2 \le c_i^T x + d_i ~~~~~~~ 1 \le i < N\\
\end{array}
$$

where $x$ is partitioned into two groups $x = (x_1, x_2)$, is it possible to write a new optimization problem defined only over $x_2$ such that the solution to this new problem is a subset of the solution to the original problem?

Comment: I don't understand what this means. If the problem depends on both $x_1$ and $x_2$, I don't see how you can write it defined "only" over $x_2$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: The question is, if the solution to the original problem is $x^* = (x_1^*, x_2^*)$, is there _any_ convex problem (no matter how different from the original problem) over $x_2$ such that the solution to this new problem equals $x_2^*$.

Comment: "No matter how different from the original" renders this useless. Here's such a model: $\text{minimize}_{x_2}~w_1^Tx_1^*+w_2^Tx_2~\text{s.t.}~x_2=x_2^*$. Same optimal value and optimal point. I'm sure you have *some* idea of the set of models to be considered.

Comment: Fair point. But what if we're restricted to formulating the problem in terms of $w, A_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ (and specifically not in terms of the solution $x^*$)

Comment: I see no way to do so without knowing $x^*$, no.

Comment: It seems to me that if $C$ is the feasible set for $x$ in the original problem, then $D = \{x_2:\exists x_1, (x_1,x_2) \in C\}$ is convex. Then define $f(x_2) = \min_{x_2} w^T(x_1,x_2)$ and minimizing $f$ over $D$ should yield $x_2$. The question is now whether $f$ is convex.